# How to arrange numbers uniformly on a chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, optimization, summation

Let $2 \le m < n$ be natural numbers. Consider a chess board of size $n*n$. Since $m < n$ this chess board will contain finitely many smaller chess boards of size $m*m$. E.g. a 3x3 board will contain 4 boards of size 2x2.

The natural numbers form 1 to $n^2$ are kept on each of the squares of the $n*n$ chess board in some order. Let $U$ be the $m*m$ board such that the sum of the numbers in it maximum and let $L$ be the $m*m$ board such that the sum of the numbers in it minimum.

**Question 1**: How do we arrange the numbers in the $n*n$ board so the $U - L$ is minimum?

**Question 2**: Can we have a theoretical upper bound on $U - L$ in terms of $m$ and $n$?

This is roughly equivalently to saying that we want to distribute the numbers in such a way that their sum is as uniform as possible.

Comment: I would go for a pattern with filling the black squares with the $\approx n^2/2$ smaller numbers, and the white squares with the bigger numbers in reverse order. Just an idea, no proof here, but I would be not surprised if this is optimal in some sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I would probably go with a pattern like this:

[image]

Filling the black squares with half of the smaller numbers increasing from top to bottom, and filling the white squares with the rest of the numbers in reverse order.

This is not a proof, just an idea. I would not be surprised if this turnes out to be optimal in some sense.

---

The reason why I believe that this is a near-optimal (if not optimal) solution is that every second left-right pair will give the same sum $1+n^2$, or $17$ in the example above. Also the sum of top-bottom pairs are very close to each other. Take a large $n$ and look at some sub square $m\times m$. It will mostly consist left-right pairs with sum $1+n^2$, and some very similar top-bottom pairs. The sub-square sum can therefore not differ so much.